# Different NaN value in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I supposed there only one `NaN` value in Java and C# but I found that there are some different types of `NaN` values in C++. Do they have the same meaning? What is the difference between them:

```
cout << numeric_limits<double>::infinity() - numeric_limits<double>::infinity() << endl; // -nan(ind)
cout << numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() << endl;//nan
if ((numeric_limits<double>::infinity() - numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) == numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()) {
        cout << "THE SAME" << endl;
} 
else {
    cout << "NOT THE SAME"<<endl;
}
```

It prints out `NOT THE SAME`, but when I use `std::isnan()` to test if the value is `NaN` or not both are true.

```
isnan(numeric_limits<double>::infinity() - numeric_limits<double>::infinity());// true
isnan(numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()); // true
```

Comment: It's important to note that IEEE-754 NaN values are never equal to any value... including *themselves* (in fact, any comparison involving a NaN is always false, so they never compare != to themselves too). So "THE SAME" should never be printed, and if the C# or Java equivalent code does print them, then it's not behaving correctly.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you, I will remember that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia explains what are Nan and quiet Nan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

These concepts are implemented in C++:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan

Quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan:

> There are many different NaN values with different sign bits and payloads, see `std::nan` and `std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN`.
>
> NaN values never compare equal to themselves or to other NaN values.
>   Copying a NaN is not required, by IEEE-754, to preserve its bit
>   representation (sign and payload), though most implementation do.
>
> Another way to test if a floating-point value is NaN is to compare it
>   with itself: `bool is_nan(double x) { return x != x; }`

It is important to note that IEEE754 (the most common way to represent floating point numbers) doesn't define **one NaN** but **one format to represent NaN** (which means several numbers can be NaNs). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN

> All NaNs in IEEE 754-1985 have this format:
>
> - *sign* = either 0 or 1.
> - *biased exponent* = all 1 bits.
> - *fraction* = anything except all 0 bits (since all 0 bits represents infinity).